# Loop through Array and sum up values with same id

Tags: php, arrays

I have a total black out. I have one array with n elements which has the results of a team, such as:

array(teamid, wins, losses, draws, goals);

```
array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
array(2, 2, 3, 4, 5);
array(1, 1, 2, 2, 6);
array(2, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

I want to iterate through this array and sum up the values for each team-id in a second array. Such as:

```
$results = getResults();
$final = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
foreach ($results as $res) {
if ($res['team_id'] == $result['team_id']) {
...
}
}
}

foreach ($final as $finalresult) {
...print result
}
```

In the end I want an array with e.g. in this example 2 values with 2 different team ids, each values summed up, but I have a blackout at the moment.

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: your data example and the code don't match; this makes it very hard to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is confusing, but I guess it will give a hint:

```
$results = getResults();
$final = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    if(!isset($final[$result['team_id']])) {
        $final[$result['team_id']] = $result['wins'];
    } else {
        $final[$result['team_id']] += $result['wins'];
    }
}

foreach($final as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key . ' ' . $value . '</br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're running the loops nested, which means you're actually summing n^2 records. Assuming the array keys are the same between both arrays, then you'd only need a single loop:

```
$arr1 = array(...);
$arr2 = array(...);
$sum = 0;

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $sum += $arr1[$key] + $arr2[$key];
}
```

If the keys aren't the same,t hen you'll have to figure out to match up the members of the two arrays.